# Application code for support package is not complete

Tags: marklogic

I created a sample application in Marklogic & tried to generate a support package from Application Builder, as described in **Navigating in Application Builder** section (page 16) of appbuilder.pdf.
This zip file shows size as 612 KB , but contains only 4 XML files, as

> info.xml
>
> 8054898124527514592.xml
>
> 8504172290275228263.xml
>
> 14220610187815029433.xml

PDF says zip file should contain the application folder. Seems I am missing some step.

Please share your thoughts in this regard.

Answer (score 0):

If you think this is a bug, simply report that to support at Marklogic. Describe the steps you took to create the sample app, and to create the support package, add the support package, and describe what you think is missing. They will let you know whether things are as should or not.

Note that there has been a mayor release since. Might be worth updating and trying again..

HTH!